# Local debugging of subdomain-based multi-tenant MVC app in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I'm working on a multi-tenant MVC application that uses a subdomain per tenant, i.e.:

tenant1.domain.com
tenant2.domain.com

But I'm having trouble figuring out a productive workflow for local testing and debugging this. The best I could come up with so far is to define a site element for each possible subdomain in the applicationhost.config file, and setting the subdomain I want to test as the application root URL in the MVC project settings. This works, but it means I can't test more than one tenant in a debug session.

I've tried using wildcards in the bindingInformation, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to make this kind of testing less tedious?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found so far has been to include your subdomain as a querystring variable when debugging locally.  Then, in your controller, determine whether or not you are debugging and if so, grab that querystring variable.  Otherwise, you're live and you would parse your domain.

This is quite old, but still effective:

http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/

The difference being, you would add the option for local debugging and like I said above, grab the querystring variable.  In his example, he goes to the trouble of modifying the hosts file on his machine.  The querystring variable is the easiest way around that.